# Scrolling to a specific element using browser router in react

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I am using react browser router and I would like to route to a specific Div in a component.

here is a part of my navbar.js (I won't paste the importing and everything since that is assumed to be done)

```
const Navbar = () => {
return (
    <div>
       <NavLink to='Contacts'>Contacts</NavLink>
    <div>
)
....
```

**and here is the app.js**

```
return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/Contacts' element={<Contacts />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
     </>
)
....
....
```

**Here is my contacts.js**

```
const Contacts = () = > {
return(
<div id={'1stDiv'} >First Div</div>
<div id={'2ndDiv'} >Second Div</div>
<div id={'3rdDiv'} >Third Div</div>
).....
```

All I am trying to achieve is simply going to a specific element (in this case the third div) in a component. I tried couple of things but I couldn't get it.
So basically route to the Contacts.js component and then to 3rdDiv instead of top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using `useRef` and `useEffect` hooks and [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) function:

Update your `Contacts` component as below:

```js
function Contacts() {
  const refThirdDiv = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (refThirdDiv.current) {
      refThirdDiv.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ marginBottom: "600px" }}>First Div</div>
      <div style={{ marginBottom: "600px" }}>Second Div</div>
      <div ref={refThirdDiv} style={{ marginBottom: "600px" }}>
        Third Div
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Contacts />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: how do i connect this with what I posted? I am confused. Like when I click contacts on my navbar, it still won't take me to contacts.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to say is I understand what you posted but how do I interact with it?

Comment: I assumed the route part is working already. This is what you need to to get the scroll part working.